# Bochner integral in banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

I would like to ask if it's necessary to use bochner integration when we use functions from a dual banach space??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is also something called **Pettis integral**, or weak integral. If $f : X \to B^\ast $, then $f $ is called Pettis integrable if the linear functional 
$$
B \to \Bbb {C}, b \mapsto \int \langle f (x), b \rangle d\mu (x)
$$
is well-defined and bounded. This functional is then called the weak integral of $f $.

Comment: Thank you very much. But also when it's necessary to use bochner integral in Hilbert and Banach spaces ??

Comment: @R.Ioannis: In Hilbert spaces, you can always use the weak integral, essentially since $H^\ast = H$, up to canonical identifications, thanks to the Riesz representation theorem. For Banach spaces, you need to be more specific with your question: What precisely do you want to do with the Bochner integral?